# Finding time with unknown acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

Assume an object moves from $0$ m to $a$ m with an *unknown* constant acceleration $c$ m s$^{-2}$. The moment it gets to $a$ m we know that its velocity is $b$ m s$^{-1}$. So basically:

$$
\begin{align*}
s(t_1)&=a\\
v(t_1)&=b\\
a(t)&=c \text{ for all }t
\end{align*}
$$

Now what will $t_1$ be? I have been working on this problem for quite a long time and I couldn't figure it out. I have tried some integrals but they didn't seem helpful.

Comment: Integrals? If $a(t)=c$, then $v(t)=ct+d$ for some constant $d$, and $s(t)=(c/2)t^2+dt+e$ for some constant $e$. Now you should be able to write down some useful equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, that is very useful. I was looking at the formal definitions of velocity and acceleration and trying out different integrals to solve the equation. It seems the answer is easier than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual notation:

$\left \{ \begin{align*} v&=u+at \\ s&=ut+\frac{1}{2} at^{2} \end{align*} \right. \implies s=vt-\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$

Switch to notation in this case:
\begin{align*}
  a &= bt_{1}-\frac{c}{2} t_{1}^{2} \\
  0 &= a - bt_{1}+\frac{c}{2} t_{1}^{2} \\
  t_{1} &= \frac{b\pm \sqrt{b^{2}-2ac}}{c}
\end{align*}

Check carefully for the validity of $t_{1}$